Сохранение скринов с двух браузеров
Одновременно запускаются два браузера и выполняются одинаковые операции, и в конце всех действий получаю скрин


export function take_screenshot(elementLocator) {
  if (elementLocator) {
      return elementLocator.saveScreenshot("./screen/screenshot1.png");
  }
  else {
      return browser.saveScreenshot("./screen/screenshot.png");
  }
}



Как сохранить одновременно два скрина и при этом наименование файла должно быть разные, например screenshot1.png и screenshot2.png

Если есть бэк, то номер можно с него получать. Либо добавлять какую то случайную строку, например через Math.random().
